# Why this open generic registration with constraints doesn't work

Tags: c#, autofac

I am using this in MediatR setup, but I have included all the interfaces for demonstration purposes.

```
public class Request : IRequest<Result<string>> { }
public interface IRequest<TResposne> { }

public interface IPipelineBehavior<in TRequest, TResponse>
{
    Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class Class1<TRequest, T> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, Result<T>> where TRequest : IRequest<Result<T>>
{
    public Task<Result<T>> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Class1<,>))
    .As(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>));

var container = builder.Build();
container.Resolve<IPipelineBehavior<Request, Result<string>>>();
```

this throws an error (Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException), but if I remove the generic constrain of Class1 it resolves?

Comment: and what error do you get? We don't like to guess.

Comment: Did you try registering like `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Class1<,>))
    .As(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<IRequest<Result<,>>,>));`

Comment: The error is "Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException, The requested service '' has not been registered."